# jQuery with twig template

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I seem to be facing an issue when updating links in my exiting Twig template with Symphony 2.

I looks like jQuery element does not want to load every time I am updating a link to format `href="{{ path('terms') }}`.

Below is part of index.html.twig

```
    <div class="site-header">
        <div class="main-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="menu-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-8">
                            <h1>
                                <a>Site Name</a>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-4 main-menu text-left">
                            <ul class="menu-first hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ 'About' }}</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('terms') }}">{{'Terms & Conditions' }}</a></li>
                                <li><a href="privacy">{{ 'Privacy Policy' }}</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#formname">{{ 'Subscribe' }}</a></li>
                                <li><a href="unsubscribe">{{ 'Unsubscribe' }}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-responsive hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ 'About' }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="terms">{{ 'Terms & Conditions' }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="privacy">{{ 'Privacy Policy' }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#formname">{{ 'Subscribe' }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="unsubscribe">{{ 'Unsubscribe' }}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using the old format of links (i.e. `href="terms"`) gives me exactly what I want however I was wondering what am I doing wrong when updating links to Twig format (i.e. below)

```
<li><a href="{{ path('terms') }}">{{'Terms & Conditions' }}</a></li>
```

This is my jQuery code. Error message in browser console takes me to section "Anchors corresponding to menu items" of below jQuery code so I kind of know where the error is however I am not fully sure how to fix it. My jQuery skills are very limited so I would appreciate any assistance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    'use strict';

    /************** Toggle *********************/
    // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $(".menu-first, .menu-responsive"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr("href"),
          offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
          scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 300);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       // Get container scroll position
       var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

       // Get id of current scroll item
       var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
         if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
           return this;
       });
       // Get the id of the current element
       cur = cur[cur.length-1];
       var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

       if (lastId !== id) {
           lastId = id;
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
       }                   
    });



    $(window).scroll(function(){
         $('.main-header').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
     });



    $('a[href="#top"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });


    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      slideshow: true,
      slideshowSpeed: 3000,  
      animation: "fade",
      directionNav: false,
    });


    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
        $('.menu-responsive').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });


    /************** LightBox *********************/
      $(function(){
        $('[data-rel="lightbox"]').lightbox();
      });


});
```

Comment: There is no reason twig or symfony are implicated: they are server side.

Comment: What do you mean "updating"? Are you modifying links used for AJAX requests? Can you show more code?

Comment: Hi eRIZ, i've update above code with major part of my index.html.twig. We were updating our index.html.twig, in particular with links to other pages. In the code i have updated above links are presented in 2 different ways: href="{{ path('terms') }}" - which is a twig format, and href="privacy" - that is an old format. In the above code href="privacy" works fine (jQuery carousel is loading perfectly). But when i update links to twig format (i.e href="{{ path('terms') }}") links are working fine but the to carousel is not showing. I believe problem is the jQuery code above.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure it out (as i am not an expert in jQuery), however one i have changed the above jQuery code to from href to li, all started working perfectly. Updated version of the code is posted below

```
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("li"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
        });
```